# Python wheel generation for py35 and py36 rather than generic py3

Tags: python, setuptools, python-wheel, python-packaging

With both python 3.6 and 3.7, the command `python setup.py bdist_wheel --plat-name=win_amd64` generates wheels for windows with the same name `mypackage-0.8.0-py3-none-win_amd64`.

Is it possible to get python wheels for python 3.6 and 3.7, with the names `mypackage-0.8.0-py36-none-win_amd64` and `mypackage-0.8.0-py37-none-win_amd64`? How?

Note: Simply renaming the generated wheels makes the wheel uninstallable

Comment: IMHO its not a duplicate of this question. What I want is even more specific than just saying py2 or py3. I want my wheels to be specific to py35, py36 and py37.

Comment: Tried the solution in the linked answer?

Comment: just tried and it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot @phd. This is exactly what i needed :)